# Dealing with tables in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, c#, esri-geodatabase, arccatalog

I had create a table and line feature class in ArcCatalog.
i want to deal with those tables in ArcMap.

- Read
- Add
- Delete
- Update

how could i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Read - use [IFeature](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000002q9000000) - [Value Method](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Value_Property/0025000007vv000000/)
- Add - use [ICursor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ICursor_Interface/00250000011s000000/) - [Insert Row Method](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/InsertRow_Method/002500000120000000/)
- Delete - use [IFeature](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000002q9000000) - [Delete Method](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Delete_Method/0025000007wr000000/)
- Update - use [IRow](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IRow_Interface/0025000007vr000000/) - [Store Method](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Store_Method/0025000007wv000000/)

Comment: how could i see the tables to deal with it in visual studio

Comment: * i am using access database

Comment: Can you clarify if you are using C#/arcobjects to do the following that you defined, or run some kind of macro in access?

Comment: i had create a table and featureClass using ArcCatalog , i am dealing with these tables using Access DB. i want to deal with these tables using c# code.